# Flash Can you iteratively create unique variables?

Tags: flash, variables, iteration, names

Can you use a

```
for(x:int=0; x<100; x++)
{
    var varname+x:Type = (x, something, something); 
}
```

To create one hundred unique variables?  Basically I need to make 100 variables and am wondering how you create 100 vats with out resorting to Declaring them all by hand. the problem is var whatever+x just creates a variable with whatever+x instead of creating whatever0, whatever1... to whatever99.
if it helps this is for flash and box2d.

Thanks, Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try this:

```
var holder:Object = {};

var i:uint = 0;
for(i; i<100; i++)
{
    holder["varname"+i] = i*2;
}

trace(holder.varname34); //output: 68
```

If you make a class `dynamic` then you can assign new properties to it the same way, ie:

```
package
{
    public dynamic class UniqueVarHolder extends Object
    {
        public function UniqueVarHolder()
        {
            var i:uint = 0;
            for(i; i<100; i++)
                this["myvariable"+i] = i*2;
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
var holder:UniqueVarHolder = new UniqueVarHolder();
trace(holder.myvariable10); //output: 20
```

Obviously you can assign anything you like to these variables.

I'm curious as to why you would want to do this though, you could just create an `Array` to store 100+ values without assigning them to a variable.

Comment: in all probability just using an array would be easier, but I'm attempting to create 100 unique objects in flash + box2d. this is the code I ended up settling on: `var count:int=0;
  for (count;count < 100;count++) {
   this["wavey"+count] = new B2FlxSprite(count, 100, 2, 2, _world);
   this["wavey"+count].createBody();
   this["wavey"+count].loadGraphic(ImgCube, false, false, 2, 2);
   this.add(this["wavey"+count]);
  } `   however this code results in a black screen and the game doesn't load. I don't know a way of using an array to create 100 little objects in box2d.

Comment: it does work, but box2d doesn't display the objects. the problem appears to be with box2d and not your code. I'll post on their forums. QUESTION ANSWERED!!! THANKS!!!

Comment: turns out flash and box2d can use an element in an array to store a body, so doh! you were even more right, should have just used an array. anyway, everything works now!! thanks again.